# parse string with regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to search a string for email addresses, but my regex does not work, when the string contains other characters than the email. Meaning, if I try on a small string like "me@email.com", the regex finds a match. If I insert a blank space in the string, like: " me@mail.com", the regex does not find an email match.

Here is my code(the regex pattern is from the web):

```
            string emailpattern = @"^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\""]+"

                    + @"(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\""]+)*)|(\"".+\""))@"

                    + @"((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}"

                    + @"\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+"

                    + @"[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$";
            Regex rEmail = new Regex(emailpattern);
            string str = @" me@mail.com";
            MatchCollection mcolResults = rEmail.Matches(str);
            MessageBox.Show(mcolResults.Count.ToString());
```

Please let me know what am I doing wrong.

Thank you.

Best regards,

Comment: Have a look here for a better email regex: http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`^` and `$` mean (respectively) the start and end of the input text (or line in multi-line mode) - generally used to check that the *entire* text (or line) matches the pattern. So if you don't want that, take them away.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I see now where the mistake was. I will try your suggestion when I get home. Next time I'll learn to make a regex before asking!

Answer (score 5):

Remove the ^ and the $ from the beginning and the end.  They mean "Start of string" and "End of string" respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Do you learn how to use regex or you actually need to parse email addresses?

There is an object that was especially designed to do it `MailAddress`

Here is the MSDN documentation:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/591bk9e8.aspx

When you initialize it with a string that holds a mail address that is not in the correct format, a `FormatException` will be thrown.

Good luck!

Comment: +1 Even if the OP doesn't use this answer, the MailAddress class is a great find for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First obvious problem: Your expression only matches email adresses at the start of a string.
You need to drop the ^ at the start.

^ matches the start of a string.

Answer (score 0):

The regex is correct.  e-mail addresses don't contain whitespace.

You can use escapes like \w in your regex in order to match whitespace, or you can do str.Trim() to fix your string before trying to match against it.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion; however I cannot use trim() - the strings are dynamic, and if for example it comes as "mmm me@mail.com", if i remove the whitespace the regex will match: mmmme@email.com

Comment: @Andrei: Trim does not remove all whitespace, only whitespace at the beginning and end of the string.